# Join string based on startsWith() and endsWith()

Tags: javascript, string

I have string `var str1 = 'foobarbaz'` and `var str2 = 'bazfoo'`

I want to join them based on overlapping starting and ending characters. The result I am looking for is `'foobarbazfoo'`.

I am currently doing it in a following way:

```
function merge(str1, str2) {
    var size = Math.min(str1.length, str2.length);
    index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        var ends = str1.substr(str1.length - i);
        var starts = str2.substr(0, i);

        if (ends === starts) {
            index = i;
        }
    }

    if (index === 0) {
        throw 'Strings do not overlap';
    } else {
        return str1 + str2.substr(index, str2.length);
    }
}
```

I wonder, if there is more elegant and efficient way of doing it ?

Comment: Should not the min be `str1.length, str2.length` in the first line?

Comment: @Pritam Yes, it should. Thx, will edit the question.

Comment: This should probably be moved to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ because there isn't an actual problem to fix.  OP is asking for improvement / recommendations.

Comment: _Start index from 1, because `str2.substr(0, 0)` is empty string_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it would be a good idea to add the function to the `String`'s `prototype` and using [startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)  this what i could come up with :

```js
String.prototype.merge = function(str) {
  let match;
  for (let i = this.length; i >= 0; i--)
    (str.startsWith(this.slice(i))) && (match = this.slice(i));

  return this.slice(0, this.indexOf(match)) + str.slice(str.indexOf(match), str.length)
}

let merged = 'foobarbaz'.merge('bazfoo')

console.log(merged);
```

in terms of speed, both methods are identical ( tested execution time with [Performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) )

but less lines and a [declarative rather than imperative](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-functional-programming-7f218c68b3a0) code.

feel free to choose betwee `slice` and `substring` ( [slice vs substring](https://jsperf.com/string-slice-vs-substring) )